# How do I overcome a naming conflict using Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

My mapper:

```
@Mapper(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface HoursLocRecord_to_MasterHoursDtoMapper extends StandardMapper<HoursLocRecord, MasterHoursDto> {
        @Mapping(source = "totalOperatingHours.value", target = "totalHours")
        @Mapping(source = "trigger.value", target = "trigger")
        MasterHoursDto map(HoursLocRecord data);
```

}

Target bean:

```
public class HoursDto implements IAssetInfo, Serializable {
  private Double totalHours;
  private Long trigger;
}
```

Source bean:

```
public class HoursLocRecord implements Serializable {
  protected ParsedDecimal totalOperatingHours;
  protected ParsedUnsignedShort trigger;
}
```

ParsedUnsignedShort

```
public class ParsedUnsignedShort {
  protected int value;
}
```

So you can see above that Trigger is an ParsedUnsignedShort in the 'source' and a Long in the 'target'.  There is a name collision somewhere as I am getting this:

> Error:(42, 6) java: Can't map property
>   "cat.tmatic.mh.domain.pl6xx.ParsedUnsignedShort trigger" to
>   "java.lang.Long trigger". Consider to declare/implement a mapping
>   method: "java.lang.Long
>   map(cat.tmatic.mh.domain.pl6xx.ParsedUnsignedShort value)".

The strange thing is I am not mapping those two!  I am mapping **trigger.value** to **trigger**.  I think I am getting a name collision but cannot overcome it.  We had to rename one variable to overcome this but mapstruct must be smarter than that.  Help!

### UPDATE

Thanks to Rohan Bhattacharya below I remade my test without the StandardMapper.class (he didn't use it) that I was extending.  It compiled.

```
public interface StandardMapper<From, To> {

  /**
   * Maps from one object to another.
   */
  To map(From from);

  /**
   * Update the object.
   */
  To update(From from, @MappingTarget To to);
}
```

So then I hooked it back up and removed the 'update' method and bam, it compiled. Apparently when using the @MappingTarget annotation I am getting the above error.  The generated code must try to use/create the same method and I get the mappingError.  Since I don't need the 'update' I can remove it and call this closed, but I think this is still a bug in Mapstruct.

Comment: It may also have to do with autoboxing from `int` to `Long`. But I think the solution the error message suggests is reasonable, just declaring that one method should fix your issue.

Comment: I tried that and couldn't figure it out either. Also, it seems to do those conversions for us.  Int to a long should work, but maybe not the other way around. Actually, that is not what I want to do.  I want it to map an int to a long, not a ParsedUnsignedShort to a long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you effectively created a mapper like this (note, extends missing):

```java
@Mapper(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface HoursLocRecord_to_MasterHoursDtoMapper  {

        //  your overriden method To map(From from);
        @Mapping(source = "totalOperatingHours.value", target = "totalHours")
        @Mapping(source = "trigger.value", target = "trigger")
        MasterHoursDto map(HoursLocRecord data);

        // no mappings defined here, so MapStruct will try to generate
        // those missing mapping based on name similarity.
        MasterHoursDto update(HoursLocRecord from, @MappingTarget MasterHoursDto to);
```

If you want to keep using the base class you could do something like this:

```java
@Mapper(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface HoursLocRecord_to_MasterHoursDtoMapper extends StandardMapper<HoursLocRecord, MasterHoursDto> {
        @Mapping(source = "totalOperatingHours.value", target = "totalHours")
        @Mapping(source = "trigger.value", target = "trigger")
        MasterHoursDto map(HoursLocRecord data);

        @InheritConfiguration // tell MapStruct to apply the same mappings as the method above with the same source / target
        MasterHoursDto update(HoursLocRecord from, @MappingTarget MasterHoursDto to);
```

Comment: Yup.  That did it.  Thanks for the help!